# Issues when trying to manage PIM through the API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to activate eligible roles through the API but it seems like most related request have been deprecated.

The one that looks the most related to what I'm trying to accomplish is "   governanceRoleAssignmentRequest". 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/3961598a89b7e33c2629b39d7065d87b71a8bdde/api-reference/beta/resources/governanceroleassignmentrequest.md

When executing the following request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/roleAssignmentRequests
```

I can't understand why this error message show up

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": "The tenant has not onboarded to PIM.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "7d46ceb7-633e-4dc2-9a23-83485913f254",
        "date": "2020-03-05T11:07:39"
    }
}
```

The permissions are configured as written in the documentation meanings that I have PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources consented.

The account has an eligible role and I have an activation request waiting for approval from an other account for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the changes to PIM API as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/azure-ad-roles-features#api-changes) you now need to replace **azureResources** with **aadroles** to make the request work e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/aadroles/roleAssignmentRequests`