# Entra ID PIM - Powershell + Graph Rest API - create role assignments

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-rest-api

I need to create powershell code for adding PIM role assignments on azure subscription scope.
I have prepared below presented code:

```
$subscriptionid = "subID"
$tenantId = "tenantID"
$clientId = "ClientID"
$clientSecret = "ClientSecret"

$secureClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientId, $secureClientSecret)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionid

Connect-MgGraph -TenantID $tenantId -ClientSecretCredential $credential
$auth_token = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token
```

I am using `$auth_token`, my registered application is added to Global Administrator group in EntraID. I am trying to use Microsoft Graph Rest API (MS documentation - [Graph rest API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroleassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell)). I have code prepared:

```
$body_json = @"
    "roleDefinitionId": "Azure RBAC Contributor role ID",
    "resourceId": "My Azure Subscription ID",
    "subjectId": "My Entra ID group ID",
    "assignmentState": "Eligible",
    "type": "AdminAdd",
    "schedule": {
      "type": "Once",
      "startDateTime": "2023-11-12T23:37:43.356Z",
      "endDateTime": "2024-11-08T23:37:43.356Z"
    }
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -method POST `
    -uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/privilegedAccess/azureResources/roleAssignmentRequests" `
    -Body $body_json `
    -Headers @{"Content-type"="application/json";"Authorization"="Bearer $auth_token"}
```

Once I run the script I am still facing error code

```
Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.","innerError":{"date":"2023-10-30T18:29:03","request-id":"cdbbd9ac-aead-4f5f-9e55-8013d4b6a554","client-request-id":"cdbbd9ac-aead-4f5f-9e55-8013d4b6a554"}}}
```

Comment: Can you decode the access token and check if PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup API permissions is present?

Comment: Application permissions are not supported to perform the action. Hence user interaction is needed to create the role assignments. Use `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup"` and run this script https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroleassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#request

Comment: OK, what should I pass under this variable --> $privilegedAccessId ?

Comment: Refer this script in this QnA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257384/graph-api-call-to-make-aad-role-assignment-request by ravishekharreddy yanamala

Comment: Pass azureResources as $privilegedAccessId and try

Comment: Added scopes `"PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup,PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources,PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources"`, used command `New-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessRoleAssignmentRequest -PrivilegedAccessId "azureResources" -BodyParameter $params` and I got error `New-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessRoleAssignmentRequest_Create: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.`

Comment: To resolve the error  assign **Privileged role Administrator** role to the user

Comment: Also make sure to assign (owner or user access administrator) on the resource according this MsDoc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroleassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-administrator-assigns-user-to-a-role

Comment: If still the issue persists, connect MgGraph with Directory.AccessAsUser.All and PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD scope too

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, I added my user to Global Admins and to role you mentioned, I run `Connect-MgGraph` on all scopes you suggested, and still the same error message. And really this API/Powershell SDK command does not work with SPN credentials, only user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: To create governance role assignment request for the group, the application or the user must have  **`PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup`** delegated API permission.

- Application permissions are not supported to perform the action as per the [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroleassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#permissions). Hence user interaction is needed to create the role assignments.
- Hence, if you want to use the Azure AD Application to create roles then use of [**access on behalf of a user**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http) flow to generate access token.
- Make sure the access token contains the required scopes.

I assigned the user **Privileged role Administrator** like below:

[image]

And directly use the below script to create role assignments:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.AccessAsUser.All", "PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureAD", "PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureADGroup", "PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources", "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureAD", "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup", "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources"

$params = @{
    roleDefinitionId = "e8cef6f1-e4bd-4ea8-bc07-4b8d950f4477"
    resourceId = "226cf998-ddcc-4005-acfb-xxxx"
    subjectId = "d0e182b5-0fed-4f44-9916-xxxx"
    assignmentState = "Eligible"
    type = "AdminAdd"
    reason = "Assign an eligible role"
    schedule = @{
        startDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse("2023-10-31T02:19:11.77+05:30")
        endDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse("2024-07-26T02:19:11.77+05:30")
        type = "Once"
    }
}

$privilegedAccessId= "aadRoles"
New-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessRoleAssignmentRequest -PrivilegedAccessId $privilegedAccessId -BodyParameter $params
```

[image]

**If still the issue persists,** change **azureResources** with **aadroles** as suggested by *SaurabhSharma* in this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544124/issues-when-trying-to-manage-pim-through-the-api)

I tried to create the governance role assignment request via Rest API with above permissions using access token and roles and the request is successful:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/aadRoles/roleAssignmentRequests

{
"resourceId": "226cf998-ddcc-4005-acfb-xxxx",
"roleDefinitionId": "644ef478-e28f-4e28-b9dc-3fdde9aa0b1f",
"subjectId": "10468df0-7214-4ef8-8ec3-xxxx",
"type": "AdminAdd",
"assignmentState": "Eligible",
"schedule": {
"startDateTime": "2023-10-31T02:19:11.77+05:30",
"endDateTime": "2024-07-26T02:19:11.77+05:30",
"type": "Once"
}
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Graph api call to make AAD role assignment request not working - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257384/graph-api-call-to-make-aad-role-assignment-request) by Siva-kumar-selvaraj

Comment: Thanks for these hints, but still got the same error, i did all you suggested, tried via poweshell and rest api and still 403 error message.

Comment: What are you passing for resourceId? Try passing tenantid instead of subscriptionid?

Comment: Tried, and the same error. I am passing $roleDefinitionId = "RBAC built in role like Contributor ID", $resourceId = "tenant or subscription ID", $subjectId = "My test Entra ID group Object ID"

Comment: Did you assign Privileged role Administrator role to the user?

Comment: My user is added to Global Administrator and Privileged role Administrator Entra ID roles.

Comment: Connect to MgGraph with proper scopes as me? including "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" scope?

Comment: I run the same powershell code, this piece of code you pasted in the post, powershell SDK command and body params.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255825/discussion-between-rukmini-and-tester81).